# How to reference users in microservices

Tags: microservices

In the company I'm working in, we try to make our monolothic application evolve into a microservice architecture.
The monolithic app has of course a user table, let's say it's called UserA, and it holds the main user information (name, email, password, ...).  The module I'm working on is an application on its own, but relies on the monolith for its user base. However it also has its own user table (UserB), which holds information and settings specific to this module.
Each UserB has a reference to UserA, but not every UserA has a corresponding UserB because not every user uses the module.

Then what's the best way for each table to reference a user ?

- Should each table in the module, including UserB, have a reference to UserA ?
- Should each table in the module reference UserB, and only UserB reference UserA ?

Right now the second option is more or less implemented. But that makes it hard for a user who would use the exposed API to switch between UserA and UserB, knowing that they have different ids. When authenticated, they know their UserA id, but they have to guess their UserB id via a specific endpoint before using the module's specific endpoints.

The first option sounds way better when as I'm writing this. But I'd love some ideas and explanations...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to choose a Single Sign-On solution for authenticating users across multiple applications based on your solution architecture (whether it is a cloud-based or a client-server).

For example, if you were using Microsoft Azure cloud then you would use Azure Active Directory. If you are using a client-server architecture then you would have to implement your own SSO mechanism to authenticate users, or (as someone noted in the comments below my response) to use an existing Identity Management Software https://financesonline.com/identity-management/

Once the user is authenticated, every application can store their own profile specific information about the user.

Comment: "If you are using a client-server architecture then you would have to implement your own SSO mechanism to authenticate users" This may be not the best of all advices. I would encourage to change the advice to "use Identity Management `(IAM)` like keycloak, okta, auth0, ory etc.